# Force ng-include to re-render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to make `ng-include` re render if a $scope variable changes. Example.

```
<div ng-include src="'assets/courses/templates/editModules/'+currentEditExercise.editTemplate"></div>
```

My problem is that if the currentExercise.editTemplate changes but it has the same template file. It doesn't re render thus not firing the controller to update the currentExercise model.

on controller:

```
$scope.currentEditExercise = param.exercise;
```

on ng-include template:
i call a child controller for that template.

```
$scope.exercise = $scope.$parent.currentEditExercise;
```

Comment: Changes to your data model should change the content rendered. Are you doing some sort of server side dynamic content? Please show all relevant code

Comment: I think @charlietfl is right, but have you tried `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: can't call $apply() says its already running.

Comment: No server side content.

Comment: it works if the template value is different.

Comment: does `{{'assets/courses/templates/editModules/'+currentEditExercise.editTemplate}}` on the next line giving you desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `ng-include` sources are cached.
This caching can be prevented by adding a random query string to the template url:

Replace:

```
$scope.currentEditExercise = param.exercise;
```

With:

```
$scope.currentEditExercise = param.exercise + '?r=' + Math.random();
```

So, whenever you change `currentEditExercise`, the complete url *will* change, even if `param.exercise` doesn't.